# How to display a list of children that have the tag "toVerify"?

Tags: java, aem

```
private static JSONArray getListOfChildPagesAsJSON(Page page) {
    JSONArray pagesArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        Iterator<Page> childPages = page.listChildren();
        while (childPages.hasNext()) {
            Page childPage = childPages.next();
            JSONObject pageObject = new JSONObject();
            pageObject.put(childPage.getTitle(), childPage.getPath());
            pagesArray.put(pageObject);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return pagesArray;
}
```

**I have a method that outputs children along the path, how can I change it to output children that has a tag `toVerify`**

Comment: Also, you could create a query to get only the pages with the given tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
if (Arrays.stream(childPage.getTags()).anyMatch("toVerify"::equals)) {
    pageObject.put(childPage.getTitle(), childPage.getPath());
    pagesArray.put(pageObject);
}
```

Comment: Especially that `"toVerify"::equals` is neat. But the OP wants to output all, not anyMatch, but filter/forEach.

Comment: @JoopEggen the snippet is intended to be placed in OP's `while` loop. I didn't want to refactor all the code to use `Streams` and `lambdas`.

Comment: I see now, should have read a bit carefully